# How to check in a list of shapefiles whether a point falls inside AND it is the same of a given FIELD?

Tags: python, list, gdal, shapefile, osgeo

I am drawing address points and checking if they are inside a large shapefile.
However, now I also want to check if they fall inside type URBAN. This information comes in terms of a list of features in which one of the columns is TYPE. I pass if the point I want is urban or not (urban=True)

My code for the cointaining point:

```
def get_random_point_in_polygon(region, urban=None):
    while True:
        address = ogr.Geometry(ogr.wkbPoint)    
        address.AddPoint(random.uniform(region.get_region().geometry().GetEnvelope()[0],
                                    region.get_region().geometry().GetEnvelope()[1]),
                     random.uniform(region.get_region().geometry().GetEnvelope()[2],
                                    region.get_region().geometry().GetEnvelope()[3]))
        if region.get_region().geometry().Contains(address) and XXXXXXXXXX:
            return address
```

Region is a large shapefile 
Now I also have a list of other 52 features that are all inside region.
They have a FIELD that contains the information URBAN or RURAL.

I want to fulfill my XXXXXX with a code that says: 'if address is inside any features in the list that FIELD = URBAN'

Any ideas?
Something like:

```
any(x in a for x in b)
```

but for shapefiles...

Comment: Ahhhh! Somebody, please!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think I found a solution, although rather cumbersome.
ShapesInput.urban is a list of features

But, note that this code is extremely cost. And given that urban areas are much smaller than rural areas, it does take a long time.

Well, it works...

```
def get_random_point_in_polygon(region, urban=True):
    while True:
        address = ogr.Geometry(ogr.wkbPoint)
        address.AddPoint(random.uniform(region.get_region().geometry().GetEnvelope()[0],
                                    region.get_region().geometry().GetEnvelope()[1]),
                     random.uniform(region.get_region().geometry().GetEnvelope()[2],
                                    region.get_region().geometry().GetEnvelope()[3]))
        if region.get_region().geometry().Contains(address):
            if urban is True:
                for item in ShapesInput.urban:
                    if item.geometry().Contains(address):
                        return address
            else:
                return address
```